# If I plug in external earbuds, it only works the internal mic

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, jack

This issue happens in every Linux distro I have tried. My earbuds mic is recognized and works on Windows.

My earbuds are the simple PS4 ones: [url][https://www.amazon.com/Official-Sony-Playstation-Earbud-PACKAGING/dp/B01DCYWI96[/url]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DCYWI96)

Laptop: Huawei Matebook D 2020, AMD Ryzen 5 3500U.

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: acp [acp], device 0: DMIC capture dmic-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

then

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

then

```
$ pacmd list-cards
3 card(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.1>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 6
        properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xc05c8000 irq 71"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.1/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1002"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
                device.product.id = "15de"
                device.product.name = "Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Uscita «Digital Stereo (HDMI)» (priority 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Uscita «Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI)» (priority 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Uscita «Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI)» (priority 800, available: no)
                off: Spento (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <off>
        ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "acp"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HUAWEI-NBLK_WAX9X-M1030-NBLK_WAX9X_PCB"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_acp3x_rn"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.5/acp_pdm_mach.0/sound/card2"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "15e2"
                device.product.name = "Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor"
                device.string = "2"
                device.description = "Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                input:stereo-fallback: Ingresso «Stereo» (priority 51, available: unknown)
                input:multichannel-input: Ingresso «Multi canale» (priority 1, available: unknown)
                off: Spento (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <input:stereo-fallback>
        sources:
                alsa_input.pci-0000_03_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0.stereo-fallback/#0: Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor Stereo
        ports:
                analog-input: Ingresso analogico (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

                multichannel-input: Ingresso multi canale (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

    index: 2
        name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.6>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        owner module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xc05c0000 irq 72"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.6"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "15e3"
                device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
                device.string = "1"
                device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        profiles:
                input:analog-stereo: Ingresso «Stereo analogico» (priority 65, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo: Uscita «Stereo analogico» (priority 6500, available: unknown)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Duplex stereo analogico (priority 6565, available: unknown)
                off: Spento (priority 0, available: unknown)
        active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
        sinks:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo/#0: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Stereo analogico
        sources:
                alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Stereo analogico
                alsa_input.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo/#2: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Stereo analogico
        ports:
                analog-input-mic: Microfono (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                analog-output-speaker: Altoparlanti (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                analog-output-headphones: Cuffie analogiche (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
```

then

```
$ sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
                     UTENTE      PID ACCESSO COMANDO
/dev/snd/controlC0:  alessandro  15754 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC1:  alessandro  15754 F.... pulseaudio
/dev/snd/controlC2:  alessandro  15754 F.... pulseaudio
```

then

```
$ pacmd list-sources
3 source(s) available.
    index: 0
        name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_03_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0.stereo-fallback>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 9030
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: yes
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        sample spec: s32le ch 2 48000 Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 85,33 ms
        card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0>
        module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "32"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = ""
                alsa.id = "DMIC capture dmic-hifi-0"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "acp"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HUAWEI-NBLK_WAX9X-M1030-NBLK_WAX9X_PCB"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_acp3x_rn"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.5/acp_pdm_mach.0/sound/card2"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "15e2"
                device.product.name = "Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor"
                device.string = "hw:2"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "32768"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "8192"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "stereo-fallback"
                device.profile.description = "Stereo"
                device.description = "Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor Stereo"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-input: Ingresso analogico (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:

        active port: <analog-input>
    index: 1
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo.monitor>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 1030
        volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        sample spec: s16le ch 2 44100 Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        fixed latency: 100,14 ms
        monitor_of: 0
        card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.6>
        module: 8
        properties:
                device.description = "Monitor of Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Stereo analogico"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xc05c0000 irq 72"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.6"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "15e3"
                device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
                device.string = "1"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
  * index: 2
        name: <alsa_input.pci-0000_03_00.6.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        state: SUSPENDED
        suspend cause: IDLE
        priority: 9039
        volume: front-left: 13118 /  20% / -41,92 dB,   front-right: 13118 /  20% / -41,92 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 6554 /  10% / -60,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 0,00 ms
        max rewind: 0 KiB
        sample spec: s16le ch 2 44100 Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 0
        linked by: 0
        fixed latency: 100,14 ms
        card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_03_00.6>
        module: 8
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC256 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC256 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xc05c0000 irq 72"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.6"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.6/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "15e3"
                device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
                device.access_mode = "mmap"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Stereo analogico"
                device.description = "Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller Stereo analogico"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC256"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0256,19e5322b,00100002"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-input-mic: Microfono (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

then

```
$ pacmd list-source-outputs
0 source output(s) available.
[/code]

[code]
$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_acp3x_pdm_dma      16384  1
snd_acp3x_rn           16384  1
snd_soc_core          323584  3 snd_acp3x_rn,snd_soc_dmic,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma
snd_hda_codec_realtek   143360  1
snd_compress           32768  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,huawei_wmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          57344  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         167936  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          106496  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               147456  8 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_timer              45056  1 snd_pcm
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
snd                   114688  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```